# Recommendation on How to handle Database attributes inserted later but not nullable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database-design, entity-framework-core

I have a `Vehicle class` which is used for mapping to the database, some of the attributes or properties of the `Vehicle` entity will be updated by different departments,

e.g a Vehicle Manager will add a new `Vehicle` to the database with all the properties with `[Required]` data notation given.

The Licensing department will add `Vehicle_NaTIS_Documents` and `Vehicle_License_Documents`

The Transport department will add `Proof_of_Delivery` and `Purchase_Documents` and so on.

The problem is that when the Vehicle Manager first adds an new entity of `Vehicle` all the other attributes (`Vehicle_NaTIS_Documents, Vehicle_License_Documents...`) will be null and then get updated later by their respective department.

Since every book about databases recommends that **NULLs in a relation be avoided as much as possible**, I am worried about this Model is there any recommendation to avoid having NULL for the other attributes

```
    public class Vehicle
    {
        public int VehicleID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Order_Number { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Registration_Number { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Make { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Model { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Chassis_Number { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Engine_Number { get; set; }

        public string Proof_of_Delivery { get; set; }

        public string Purchase_Document { get; set; } 

        public string Vehicle_NaTIS_Document { get; set; } 

        public string Vehicle_License_Document { get; set; } 

        public string Vehicle_Invoice { get; set; } 
   }
```

Comment: Aren't Proofs of Delivery etc. entities in their own right? Like, why are most of the property names pluralized?

Comment: You recommend that i make create another table for this entities and use `VehicleID` as a foreign Key, meaning i would need two more tables for the other two departments (Licensing and Transport) to add the other attributes?

Comment: Maybe, but so far I'm only asking questions. Where's the rest of the information of these documents stored? Maybe you only need foreign keys, or association tables, I don't know.

Comment: Foreign keys would be a great solution, but I am worried about the number of tables I will have to create just to avoid having a property or attribute being `null`. for example if the are 5 properties or attributes each updated by a different department, it means I will have to create 5 tables for each property, wont that make the database difficult to maintain?

Comment: One rule of thumb that I live by is "Avoid rules of thumb".  (</irony>)  It is a gross oversimplification to say **"avoid nulls if at all possible"** - This is the same simplistic school of thought as "redundancy is evil" or "don't start a sentence with 'But'".  Null means you don't know or you don't care.  The fact that it doesn't distinguish between these is disconcerting to some people.  However, "don't know/don't care" is a perfectly valid fact to record in some situations. This rule of thumb exists to discourage creation of a 0NF table with a zillion null columns-which is just bad design.

Comment: All of that being said, there's something to consider about what Gert Arnold is saying about maybe things that happen at different times should be considered different entities (perhaps with 1:1 relationships to your base table).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using **default values** for each non-nullable column that is being deferred to next task in workflow.

Without knowing the details of your application it's hard to say what exactly those default values will be.

Since you have `string` as type of the `Vehicle_License_Document` I'm assuming it is a file path or unique ID in the License Documents table that contains the file bytes. In that case you could use

- a default file path (decide on whether to use existent or non-existent file path)
- or a default ID (decide on whether to use null file bytes or dummy file bytes)